# Is there any way to mirror or symmetrize a Muscle Tool?

Tags: rigging

The Blender Muscle Tools creator no longer seems to be responding to queries for help. I would also like to know if there are any alternative methods for muscle rigging, as the 'stretch constraint' and cage deformer functions are in a primitive state at this point.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it is not solution to your question but you may like to try this one. It does X-Mirror with single click and has more advanced options.
https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system